# Stop re rendering on unused state changes in the current component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, in `Container` component I have defined a state variable called `a`. In it, `a` is only changed but not used in the `view`. When I'm running this, on each `click`, `Container` and `Inner` both are re-rendered. Can I stop re-render for `Container` component?

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, memo } from 'react'
import { assertIsNotNull } from '../../common/assertion-functions'

const Inner = ({ num }: { num: number }) => {
    console.log('Inner')

    return <div>{num}</div>
}

const Container = () => {
    console.log('Container')

    const ref = useRef(null)
    const [a, setA] = useState(1)

    useEffect(() => {
        const curr = ref.current
        assertIsNotNull(curr)
        const ele = curr as HTMLDivElement

        ele.addEventListener('click', () => {
            setA((num) => {
                return num + 1
            })
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div style={{ padding: '30px', backgroundColor: 'gray' }} ref={ref}>
            <Inner num={a} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default memo(Container)
```

Originally I was trying to capture the 'click and drag' amount on an element and reflect the pixel difference (current_pos - original_position) on another element's `css` `translate` property. `onDrag` doesn't do what I want so I'm using few event listeners in `JavaScript` way.

For the questing I changed it to a `click` for the simplicity using `addEventListener` to update the status.

Answer (score 0):

Container has to re-render whenever it's state changes, otherwise Inner wouldn't re-render.

If you want Inner to change without Container rendering, move the state down to Inner, into redux, or into context that can be used to update the `a` state without Container having to see it or pass it down to Inner.